# if condition doesn't detect null statement js

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, null

I am quite irritated by the problem in this script:

```
exercices.forEach(function(element){
if(i<parseInt(nb_exercices)){

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "ajax/getExercice.php",
        data:{id:element["exercice_id"]},
        success : function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data) 

            if(data["categorie"] == "1"){
                if(!modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").hasClass("full")){

                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").append(`
                            <li><a href="exercices/`+data["exercice_id"]+`" target="_blank">`+data["name"]+`</a></li>
                            <div>Nb séries : `+element["nb_series"]+`, Nb répétitions : `+element["nb_repetitions"]+` - Charge : `+element["charge"]+` `+element["unit"]+`</div>
                        `)
                }else{
                    modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").removeClass("full")
                    modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").append(`
                            <li><a href="exercices/`+data["exercice_id"]+`" target="_blank">`+data["name"]+`</a></li>
                            <div>Nb séries : `+element["nb_series"]+`, Nb répétitions : `+element["nb_repetitions"]+` - Charge : `+element["charge"]+` `+element["unit"]+`</div>
                        `)
                }
            }else{
                console.log(data)
                console.log(element)
                if(element["charge"] == null){
                    if(!modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").hasClass("full")){
                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").append(`
                                <li><a href="exercices/`+data["exercice_id"]+`" target="_blank">`+data["name"]+`</a></li>
                                <div>Nb séries : `+element["nb_series"]+`, Nb répétitions : `+element["nb_repetitions"]+` - 

                                    <form class="charge_form form-inline" method="post" action="">
                                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                            <label for="charge" class="mr-1">Charge : </label>
                                            <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control col-md-3" name="charge" placeholder="">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="exercice_id" value="`+data["exercice_id"]+`" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="nex_training" value="`+exercices.indexOf(element)+`" />
                                            <input type="hidden" name="training_id" value=`+training_id+` />
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary little-button" name="charge_submit" value="OK">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                <div>`)

                    }else{
                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").removeClass("full")
                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").append(`
                                <li><a href="exercices/`+data["exercice_id"]+`" target="_blank">`+data["name"]+`</a></li>
                                <div>Nb séries : `+element["nb_series"]+`, Nb répétitions : `+element["nb_repetitions"]+` - 
                                    Charge : `+element["charge"]+` `+element["unit"]+`</div>
                                <div>`)

                    }

                }else{

                    if(!modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").hasClass("full")){

                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").append(`
                            <li><a href="exercices/`+data["exercice_id"]+`" target="_blank">`+data["name"]+`</a></li>
                            <div>Nb séries : `+element["nb_series"]+`, Nb répétitions : `+element["nb_repetitions"]+` - Charge : `+element["charge"]+` `+element["unit"]+`</div>
                        `)
                    }else{
                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").removeClass("full")
                        modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").append(`
                                <li><a href="exercices/`+data["exercice_id"]+`" target="_blank">`+data["name"]+`</a></li>
                                <div>Nb séries : `+element["nb_series"]+`, Nb répétitions : `+element["nb_repetitions"]+` - Charge : `+element["charge"]+` `+element["unit"]+`</div>
                            `)
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    });
    i++;
}else{
    i = parseInt(nb_exercices)
}
});
```

Each element has this format expected :

```
charge: null
exercice_id: "27"
nb_repetitions: 3
nb_series: 6
unit: "kg"
```

The problems comes to the condition :

```
if(element["charge"] == null)
```

The first element whose charge is `null` goes to the `else` instead of enter in the `if`.

The result of this problem :[image]

Instead of  : [image]

I don't know how to solve that. Can you help me?

Comment: It would be nice if you could reduce this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is it's very hard to read and reproduce your problem

Comment: @MarkMeyer I will do it

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's what `data` is, and not, say, `charge: 'null'` (i.e. "null" as a string)? Have you tried, say, `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`?

Comment: Note that the code you've shown here doesn't actually include the else associated with `if(element["charge"] == null)`. The condition it's casing on is `if(!modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").hasClass("full"))` which might be your problem

Comment: This is not null as a string , this is the null form php store in json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not `if(element["charge"] == null){` that is causing the problem, but rather the `if` statement inside of that one. Notice that if `element["charge"] == null` is true but `!modal.find(".cmodal-content").find(".cmodal-body").find("div.middle").find("ul").hasClass("full")` is false, you will reach the case where you include

```
Charge : `+element["charge"]+` `+element["unit"]+`</div>
```

producing the undesired `Charge : null kg`.

Comment: I just don't copy well the script